# Failed to start The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to set up wordpress on my ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS server but seems to not be able to get past the following error when installing or updating any packages. When I enter `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`. I get the following error.

```
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.2-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Job for php7.2-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php7.2-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.2-fpm, action "restart" failed.
● php7.2-fpm.service - The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.2-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-18 09:45:24 CST; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.2(8)
  Process: 20174 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 20174 (code=exited, status=78)

Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager...
Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain php-fpm7.2[20174]: [18-Nov-2020 09:45:24] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain php-fpm7.2[20174]: [18-Nov-2020 09:45:24] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain php-fpm7.2[20174]: [18-Nov-2020 09:45:24] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain systemd[1]: php7.2-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain systemd[1]: php7.2-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 18 09:45:24 makemctgreatagain systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager.
dpkg: error processing package php7.2-fpm (--configure):
 installed php7.2-fpm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.2-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure if I need to reinstall php or where to go from here.

Comment: Did you check the folder mentioned to see whether php-fpm.conf is there or not? There might be a php-fpm.conf.default file there instead. If so copy it to php-fpm.conf and edit it to your liking(that's another topic ;))

Comment: I am using apache2 so would I still have a php-fpm.conf? Sorry very new this.

Comment: seems I am missing /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf

Comment: Yes, you are. But does the folder /etc/php/7.2/fpm exist? Are there any files at all in it?

Comment: I ended up going the hosting route. Made life so much simpler.